# How to solve Error: YAML to JSON: yaml: line 118: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Started working on deploying a node using a helm chart. I am attempting to do some helm deployments with a `makefile` that has `upgrade` attributed to `helm upgrade $(name) . --namespace name`. So I run `make upgrade` and I got an error as shown:

```
walk.go:74: found symbolic link in path: /Users/samuelarogbonlo/Desktop/mina/helm/generic-node/Makefile resolves to /Users/samuelarogbonlo/Desktop/mina/helm/common/Makefile
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on generic-node/templates/generic-node.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 118: did not find expected key
make: *** [upgrade] Error 1
```

I have attempted to remove `| quote` but it did not change the situation and I have some guesses that it has to do with the brackets but all trials have failed.

My rendered yaml file is shown thus:

```
        - name: SECRET_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: source-libp2p-keys
              key: key
        - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: source-libp2p-keys
              key: "some-libp2p-key"
         - name: SECRET_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: private-keys
              key: key
        - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: private-keys
              key: ""
 

Error: YAML parse error on generic-node/templates/generic-node.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 118: did not find expected key
helm.go:88: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 118: did not find expected key
YAML parse error on generic-node/templates/generic-node.yaml
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
```

I really need help on how to sort this out because even my `values.yaml` file has the values of `graphql` referenced as well.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? My focus is on the part that says ```Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error```

Comment: Please show the rendered YAML (see [debugging templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/)). The error message gives you *line 118* but this refers to the rendered YAML file, not the template, so to figure out what is wrong, we need to see the rendered YAML.

Comment: Oh wow - I have updated the question. @flyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```yaml
        - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: source-libp2p-keys
              key: "some-libp2p-key"
         - name: SECRET_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: private-keys
              key: key
```

The line `- name SECRET_USERNAME` is indented one space too much. Put it at the same indentation as the previous `- name: SECRET_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Please if you can, look through this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005690/how-to-solve-this-helm-error-error-upgrade-failed-error-validating-error @flyx