# How to solve this helm error "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data"?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

This is a follow-up question to my former question on chart validation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994873/how-to-solve-error-yaml-to-json-yaml-line-118-did-not-find-expected-key)
While trying to deploy a helm chart, I have an error that shows thus:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.initContainers[1]): unknown field "mountPath" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container
make: *** [upgrade] Error 1
```

FWIW, this is the `initcontainer spec` details below:

```
spec:
      initContainers:
      {{- if .Values.libp2p.staticKeypair.enabled}}
      - name: libp2p-init-my-service
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: ['sh', '-c', '/bin/cp /libp2p-keys/* /root/libp2p-keys && /bin/chmod -R 0700 /root/libp2p-keys/']
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /libp2p-keys
          name: source-libp2p-keys 
        - mountPath: /root/libp2p-keys
          name: destination-libp2p
      {{- end }}
      - name: config-dir
        mountPath: /root/.mina-config
      - name: fix-perms
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'for dir in keys echo-keys faucet-keys; do [ -d /$dir ] && /bin/cp /$dir/* /wallet-keys; done; /bin/chmod 0700 /wallet-keys']
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/keys/"
          name: private-keys
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /wallet-keys
          name: wallet-keys
      containers:
```

What could be the possible causes and how can I handle them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with YAML so take care about the indentation since it's really important.

Since you're declaring `initContainers`, on the first level you define `Containers`; but you included the following on that level:

```
- name: config-dir
  mountPath: /root/.mina-config
```

Since `name` is actually an attribute of `Container`, it complains about `mountPath`.

I don't know where you want to mount `.mina-config`, but it should be nested inside of the `volumeMounts` attribute within a `Container` and not at the same level than the containers.